# Find characters in multiple strings

Tags: python, string, list

Find characters in multiple strings. I have a given strings as in below code block, I don't get any output, I am sure as its trying to find whole word in the list, I am looking for few characters (some thing like wild cards) I Don't want to use any library for this.

```
findChar = 'an'
a, b, c, d, e =  'Australia', 'Canada', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany'
countries = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany']

if findChar in countries:
    print(f' characters {findChar} is available.')
```

If I use below code, it works only for 1 string and not for all

```
if findChar in b:  #How to use (a,b,c,d,e)? 
    print(f' characters {findChar} is available.')
```

I am able to get the output but i need in a simple way

```
if any(str in words for words in (a,b,c,d,e) for str in ('an')):
    print(f' characters {findChar} is available.')
```

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: use a loop to loop through your list

Comment: `if any('an' in words for words in (a,b,c,d,e)):`

Comment: @deadshot Thanks, this is simple to use, will use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop you need to check using `in` for each `list` element

```py
findChar = 'an'
#a, b, c, d, e =  'Australia', 'Canada', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany'
countries = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany']

for each_country in countries: # this will give you each list element
    if(findChar in each_country): # check is findChar exists in that country
        print(f' characters {findChar} is available in the country {each_country}')
```

output

```
 characters an is available in the country Canada
 characters an is available in the country Finland
 characters an is available in the country Germany
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution using filter:

```py
findChar = 'an'
countries = ['Australia', 'Canada', 'Denmark', 'Finland', 'Germany']
result = list(filter(lambda x: findChar in x, countries))

for item in result:
    print(f' characters {findChar} is available in {item}.')
```

Comment: I have developed Connect Four Game, Want someone to validate it. How and where do I post my codes so that members can comment?

Comment: You can post the code in another question on stack overflow, or you can post it on https://repl.it/talk.